# how to replace line bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm looking to replace a line of text in a file. 
This is not a specific line #, but rather matching a certain parameter and then replace the entire line with what I want.

Looking into 'sed' seems to be an idea, problem is all the special chars included in the source/to replace strings that are confusing me in sed how to handle properly.
I also tried these are parsed variables but with no results.

Eg:
Source line to match: `PATH_FLOW=*ANYTHINGgoes*`
To be replaced with: `PATH_FLOW="file:///var/log"`

```
sed -i 's/^PATH_FLOW=*/PATH_FLOW="file:///var/log"/g' /etc/sysconfig/random_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/PATH_FLOW=/s~^.*$~PATH_FLOW="file:///var/log"~'
```

Comment: That will match any line containing 'PATH_FLOW=', because the line selection expression isn't anchored.  There's also no reason to retype the matched part, and the `/g` at the end is not useful when replacing the whole line.  Here's a simpler version: `sed -i.bak 's~^\(PATH_FLOW=\).*$~\1"file:///var/log"~'`

Comment: I didn't use `/g` in my answer.